# Need help trying to analyse this file

Tags: binary

[image]I’m new to all this Linux and reverse engineering and want to learn, I got this android firmware bin file read from a emmc and I wanted to mount it but couldn’t figure out how to but after 2 days I managed to figure out how to extract it, it was a 16gb file but I run out of space after it extracted 330gb which I used binwalk, there’s a small file named key which I just wanted to examine to see what data it has or if there’s a key of some sort, I checked with byte code and it shows as the picture which I don’t understand, so I tried to check Entropy but nothing is shown on the graph but it says falling entropy edge, so I need some help to try to find out what’s inside this file and if it’s encrypted but I’m stuck, here’s the pictures and I’ll upload the file aswell [image]

Link for the file I’m working on below

[https://www.mediafire.com/file/vcj41cac6fxrld1/key/file[enter](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vcj41cac6fxrld1/key/file%5Benter) link description here][3](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vcj41cac6fxrld1/key/file)

Comment: What is this file and its purpose on the system?

Comment: It’s meant to be a key for app, but I’m trying to find out and learn in the same process if it is encrypted and if does contain a key

Comment: So no one can help me with this file if it is encrypted and how to tackle this ?